# Protractor: Testing for 'busy indicator' / behaviour with slow internet connection

Tags: angularjs, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

I have a busy indicator that appears if the HTTP request takes longer than 1 second.  If it returns in less than 1 second, the busy indicator does not appear.

What's the best way to test this with protractor?  I'm thinking I need two test cases:

```
it('should not show busy indicator because http response is quick', function () {
    // ??
});

it('should show busy indicator because http response is taking longer than 1 second', function () {
    // ??
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to setup a configurable proxy server that the browser launched by Protractor uses. This proxy server can add a latency to requests, thus simulating a slow internet connection/network (or at least, simulating it enough for your purposes).

Such a proxy server + mini-API to allow it to be configurable is like:

```
// proxy.js

// Config ports
var PROXY_PORT = 8001;
var CONFIG_PORT = 8002;

// Latency used for all requests
var latency = 0;

// Proxy
var hoxy = require('hoxy');
var proxy = new hoxy.Proxy();
proxy.intercept('request', function(req, resp) {
  req.slow({latency: latency}); 
});
proxy.listen(PROXY_PORT);

// API Server for tests to configure latency
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  latency = req.body.latency;;
  res.send('');
});
app.listen(CONFIG_PORT);
```

The above requests the npm packages `hoxy`, `express` and `body-parser`, and each can be installed by commands like

```
npm install hoxy --save-dev
```

The above server, assuming it's saved to `proxy.js` can be launched on the command line by

```
node proxy.js
```

Note that it listens on 2 ports: 8001 for a simple HTTP proxy that adds a latency to requests, and 8002 for a simple API that listens on `/` that accepts a JSON object with a single key: `latency` with a number of milliseconds to slow all subsequent requests via the proxy.

To use the proxy in Protractor, you can add it to its configuration file, for example for Chrome, by:

```
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  proxy: {
    proxyType: 'manual',
    httpProxy: 'localhost:8001'
  }
}
```

Then in your spec file, you can create a function to set the latency for subsequent requests by

```
describe('My Component', function() {
  var http = require('http');

  function setLatency(latency) {
    return browser.controlFlow().execute(function () {
      var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
      var data = JSON.stringify({latency:latency});
      var req = http.request({
        method: 'POST',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8002,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Content-Length': data.length
        }
      }, function() {
        deferred.fulfill();
      });
      req.write(data);
      req.end();  
      return deferred.promise;
    });
  }
...
```

Note that we add the code to the control flow, and return a promise that is resolved once the request to set the latency has completed. This means we can use it in the same natural way as other protractor element finders/expectations, without having to use manual `then` callbacks.

Your actual tests depend on exactly how you're showing the busy indicator, but you should be able to do something like the following:

```
it('should not show busy indicator because http response is quick', function () {
  setLatency(900);
  element(by.css('button')).click();
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  browser.sleep(500);
  expect(element(by.css('.loading-indicator')).isPresent()).not.toBe(true);
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
  setLatency(0);
});

it('should show busy indicator because http response is taking longer than 1 second', function () {
  setLatency(2000);
  element(by.css('button')).click();
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  browser.sleep(1000);
  expect(element(by.css('.loading-indicator')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
  setLatency(0);
});
```

The above tests aren't perfect. Specifically the test that that busy indicator doesn't show doesn't actually show that it never appears. It just tests that it doesn't appear 500ms into a 900ms request.

Note the setting of `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false`. If we don't set it to `false`, then the test won't progress untill all `$http` requests have finished, which we don't want to do in this case, as we're testing the behaviour of what happens during the request.